# Python: In a for loop going through a list, how do you multiply by every other element of that list

Tags: python

Firstly, apologies if the title doesn't make complete sense. I'm still quite new to programming.

Say I have a list of masses: `list = [m1, m2, m3, m4]`

I want to get a the sum for each mass multiplied by the rest of the masses using a for loop.
i.e.

```
for i in list:
    #code here to yield
    #m1*m2 + m1*m3 + m1*m4
    #m2*m1 + ..... etc
```

How would I go about doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naively, you would need to track the current index in the loop, to know which element to skip when multiplying by the other elements. This can be done with a loop over `range(len(list))` or `enumerate(list)`.

However, there's a cleaner way that also executes much faster if the list is large. Instead of multiplying by every other element and adding up the products, multiply by the *sum* of *all* the elements, *minus* the current element. You can compute the sum of all elements up front, avoiding a lot of unnecessary repeated work:

```
l = [m1, m2, m3, m4]

# Outside the loop - this is important.
lsum = sum(l)

for i in l:
    do_whatever_with(i * (lsum - i))
```

Comment: I ended up using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `sum` function along with a `for` loop as:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4] # actual numbers for showing working code

for i, n in enumerate(my_list):
    print sum(n*j for j in my_list[:i]+my_list[i+1:])
```

which will print result as:

```
9
16
21
24
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The  best way to do this is to realize that `m2*m1+m2*m3+m2*m4 == m2*(m1+m3+m4)`, so you can simply:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    sum_i = mylist[i]*sum(mylist[:i]+mylist[i+1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this:

```
for i, mass_i in enumerate(my_list):
    sum = 0
    for j, mass_j in enumerate(my_list):
        if i != j:        
            sum += mass_i * mass_j
    print sum
```

Should be easy enough to follow although there are more elegant and efficient solutions posted here (depending on your use case - the size of the list, the number of times you would need perform the calculation, etc).